# How to invoke command manager scripts of Microstrategy using Java program without .bat file

Tags: java, microstrategy

I had created an array for commands:

```
String[] commands={"CHDIR C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MicroStrategy\\Command Manager","cmdmgr -n xyz -u pqr -p lmn -f C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Script.scp -o C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\MyScript.log"};
```

It is giving me invalid -n error.

Answer (score 1):

With the -n you should specify the project source name. Look in Developer or Project Source Manager if not sure which name is correct.
If its a single word without spaces you can provide it as is. But if it contains spaces it has to be enclosed in double quotes like `-n "My Project Source"`.
HTH!